# Hölder and Slobodeckij spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, $s\in(0,1)$, and $p\in(1,\infty)$, the Sobolev-Slobodeckij seminorm is given by
$$
[f]_{W^{s,p}}^p=\int_\Omega\int_\Omega\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}}dxdy.
$$
A) Is it true and B) if it is, is there a direct proof (without going into fractional Laplacians, interpolation spaces, etc.) that $s$-Hölder continuous functions have finite $[f]_{W^{s,p}}$ seminorm? Naively bounding $|f(x)-f(y)|$ by the Hölder norm times $|x-y|^s$  just barely fails.

Comment: Is the result even true? I thought it wasn't!

Comment: You're right, I should have phrased it more carefully, I've edited now. But I think one can find equivalent Besov spaces for both spaces that shows the inclusion.

Comment: $C^{0,s} = B^s_{\infty,\infty}$ and $W^{s,p} = F^s_{p,2}$, even when $p=2$ so that $F^s_{2,2} = B^s_{2,2}$ I'm unsure what can be done, without raising $s$, as $\ell^2 \subset \ell^\infty$ but $L^\infty(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Yes I agree that it's not looking promising. Thanks!

Comment: yw and +1; if I find the time I might look for a counterexample...!

Comment: This paper (https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_3118268_1/component/file_3118270/content) shows that for all $s \in (0,1/2)$, there is some Fourier series $f$ with pointwise Hölder exponent exactly $2s$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $s$ on $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ (hidden in theorems 3.1 and 3.3). Hence there is $C>0$ such that for almost all $x$, for $y$ close enough to $x$, $|f(y)-f(x)| \ge C |x-y|^s$. Use Cousin's lemma intelligently to show that the integral diverges. This stays a comment as I didn't proofread the paper, and the part about Cousin needs more work, I'm not even 100% sure it works

Comment: A remark on my comment: the constant $C$ as presented does not necessarily exist... Consider my previous comment moot, although I leave it under your post since the paper linked was interesting

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=(-\pi,\pi)$, $0<s<1$, and $0\leq
\delta\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Define
$$
u(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{ns}}\frac{1}{n^{\delta}}\cos
(2^{n}x),\quad x\in I.
$$
Then one can prove that $u\notin W^{s,2}(I)$. The idea is that for $0<h<1$ small
and for $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{\ell+1}}<h\leq\frac
{1}{2^{\ell}}$,
$$
\frac{h^{s}}{\log^{\delta}(1/h)}\le C\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\ell}\frac
{1}{2^{2ns}}\frac{1}{n^{2\delta}}2^{2n}h^{2}\right)  ^{1/2}\le C\Vert
\Delta_{h}u\Vert_{L^{2}(I_{h})},
$$
where $I_h=\{x\in I: x+h\in I\}$ .

On the other hand, $u\in W^{s,\infty}(I)$. The idea is to break the sum $\sum_{n=1}%
^{\infty}=\sum_{n=1}^{\ell}+\sum_{n=\ell+1}^{\infty}$, where $\ell$ is as
before.
The details are in a paper of Taibleson, Mitchell H. On the theory of Lipschitz spaces of distributions on Euclidean n-space. I. Principal properties. J. Math. Mech. 13 1964 407–479.